# Проблема с роутом в nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, роутинг

При клике на пункт меню клиники, переход на страницу происходит нормально.https://beautystars.life/  Но если я обновлю ее или просто захочу скопировать ссылку и перейти по ней, то она недоступна https://beautystars.life/kliniki  . Не могу понять что не так

Comment: как у вас роут зарегистрирован, как сайт работает, через статику `generate` или `build` ?

Comment: @ryzen  я вообще никак его не регистрировала, из коробки как есть. Через build dist не появляется, только через generate

Comment: @ryzen это может иметь отношение? DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:3000/bootstrap.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: Проверила через валидатор, куча ошибок, но в коде их нет. Что это может быть? Ошибка: случайный конец тега a.

От строки 42, колонка 826 ; до строки 42, колонка 829

>Акции</a></a></li>   Может это при генерации файлов какие то проблемы?

Comment: hydrationBailed = true;
                console.warn('Parent: ', elm);
                console.warn('Mismatching childNodes vs. VNodes: ', elm.childNodes, children); Что это может значить? Куча ошибок в консоли связанных  с hydratyng